# set attribute of every anchor in document

Tags: javascript, attributes, for-loop

I'm trying to set the `target` of every link in a page. I'm currently trying:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
for (i in x)
    i.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
```

But I get a TypeError. It works when I `setAttribute` on the `x[0]`, but not how I did it above. Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to `x[i]` instead of `i`. `i` returns the index of the link.

For array-like objects, it's recommended to use `for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++)` instead of `for(i in x)`.

Your code can be written more efficiently using the code below, because not every `a` element is a link:

```
var x = document.links;
for(var i=0, l=x.length; i<l; i++){
    x[i].setAttribute("target", "_blank");
}
```

Comment: At least in Chrome it is even necessary to use a normal `for` loop, because the `item` and `length` properties of the `NodeList` are enumerable.

Comment: WHOOPS. The anchors didn't exist yet. THank you!

Comment: enjoy the rep! have a lovely day